# ERROR: Too many data partitions

Tags: vertica

I see the following error in `vertica.log`:

```
2016-09-01 15:30:54.007 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [Txn] <INFO> Begin Txn: a00000001212c3 'Moveout: Tuple Mover'
2016-09-01 15:30:54.007 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [TM] <INFO> Tuple Mover: moving out projection rosing_epg_program_events_super
2016-09-01 15:30:54.017 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [EE] <INFO> (a00000001212c3) Moveout projection staging.rosing_epg_program_events_super
2016-09-01 15:30:54.017 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [EE] <INFO> (a00000001212c3) TM Moveout: moving out data in WOS for proj "staging.rosing_epg_program_events_super" to epoch 3061
2016-09-01 15:30:54.017 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [EE] <INFO> (a00000001212c3) Executing the moveout plan
2016-09-01 15:30:54.040 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [EE] <INFO> SortManager found maxMerges 7 too small(64 MB Assigned).
2016-09-01 15:30:54.040 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [EE] <INFO> After disabling optimization, maxMerges becomes 15.
2016-09-01 15:30:54.069 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440-a00000001212c3 [Txn] <INFO> Rollback Txn: a00000001212c3 'Moveout: (Table: staging.rosing_epg_program_events) (Projection: staging.rosing_epg_program_events_super)'
2016-09-01 15:30:54.070 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440 <LOG> @v_statistic_node0001: 00000/3298: Event Posted: Event Code:14 Event Id:261 Event Severity: Warning [4] PostedTimestamp: 2016-09-01 16:30:54.069887 ExpirationTimestamp: 2016-09-01 16:31:09.069887 EventCodeDescription: Timer Service Task Error ProblemDescription: threadShim: Too many data partitions DatabaseName: statistic Hostname: rosing-vertica.elt.stag.local
2016-09-01 15:30:54.070 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440 <ERROR> @v_statistic_node0001: {threadShim} 54000/5060: Too many data partitions
        HINT:  Verify that the table partitioning expression is correct
        LOCATION:  handlePartitionKey, /scratch_a/release/16125/vbuild/vertica/EE/Operators/DataTarget.cpp:1478
2016-09-01 15:30:54.070 TM Moveout:0x7f9438012440 [Util] <INFO> Task 'TM Moveout' enabled
```

Seems like I choose wrong field for partitioning and reached limit of partitions in WOS as described [here](https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Knowledge-Base/Understanding-Vertica-Epochs/ta-p/233749#_Toc436058724).

Task `SELECT do_tm_task('moveout');` raise the following error:

```
 Task: moveout
(Table: staging.rosing_schema_migrations) (Projection: staging.rosing_schema_migrations_super)
...
(Table: staging.rosing_epg_program_events) (Projection: staging.rosing_epg_program_events_super)
On node v_statistic_node0001:
  ERROR 5060:  Too many data partitions

(1 row)
```

Anybody know how to fix this problem?

**Update**:

I can't remove partitioning from this table:

```
ALTER TABLE rosing_epg_program_events REMOVE PARTITIONING
```

because this SQL raise the same error: Too many data partitions

**UPDATE 2**

I fixed this problem use `woot` answer. Thank you a lot!

Here is my steps for fix it:

1. Create copy of `rosing_epg_program_events` table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE staging.rosing_epg_program_events2
   LIKE staging.rosing_epg_program_events;
   ```
2. Remove partitioning from new table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE staging.rosing_epg_program_events2 REMOVE PARTITIONING;
   ```
3. Copy data from old to new table. Seems like old table contains all (!) data inserted before and after appear problem:

   ```
   INSERT /*+ DIRECT */ INTO staging.rosing_epg_program_events2
   SELECT * FROM staging.rosing_epg_program_events;
   ```
4. Drop old table:

   ```
   DROP TABLE staging.rosing_epg_program_events;
   ```
5. Rename new table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE staging.rosing_epg_program_events2 RENAME TO rosing_epg_program_events;
   ```
6. Run Moveout operation for any case. Now it works fine:

   ```
   SELECT do_tm_task('moveout');
   ```
7. Check last good epoch for any case. Now it show actual value:

   ```
   SELECT GET_LAST_GOOD_EPOCH();
   SELECT * FROM epochs WHERE epoch_number = 3064; // result of previous command
   ```

Seems like all works fine now.

Comment: One small note, just be sure your projections are correct on the new table. I had accidentally typed `INCLUDING PARTITIONS` when I meant `INCLUDING PROJECTIONS`.  I've fixed it in my answer below.

Comment: You are right. I am loose segmentation of table (now it has segmentation by all field), primary key constraint and and `AUTO_INCREMENT` filed (now it just INT filed). So, will be better to use `INCLUDING PROJECTIONS` or create table from scratch. Right?

Comment: Yep, or you can `select export_objects(...)` and change the name but I think including projection is easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` or `CREATE TABLE LIKE INCLUDING PROJECTIONS`, remove the partitions, then `INSERT /*+ DIRECT */ SELECT` to copy the data out and drop the table then rename. Also, when creating partitions, try to target a granularity somewhere under 40 partitions.  You didn't specify, but if using a timestamp, use a formula to extract out a less granular value.  For example, to do monthly, do:

```
EXTRACT (year FROM mydate) * 100 + EXTRACT (month FROM mydate)
```

You don't have to worry about using formulas in the partitioning for Vertica. It uses min/max values for the fields instead of direct matching on the partition key.